# My else statement is not effective but if statement is. Java

Tags: java

I was going to let user enter 10 names and make it as array.
Then again I will let user to enter the names they want to search, then present the search result.
However, when I search something that was not in the array, the result still shows it. Is any problem in my code? Hope anyone could help, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Main 
{
static List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main (String[]args)
{   
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);

    int i;
    String sname;

    System.out.println("Please enter 10 student names.");
    for(i=1;i<11;i++){
    name.add(input.next());
    }

    System.out.println("Namelist is " + name);
    String[] namearray = name.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println("Arraylist is "+ Arrays.toString(namearray));

    System.out.println("Please enter the names that you want to search.");
    sname=input2.nextLine();

    search(namearray, sname);
}

public static void search(String[]namearray,String sname)
{
    int i;
    boolean check;

    for(i = 0; i < namearray.length; i++){
          if(namearray[i].equals(sname))
             check=true;
          else
              check=false;
    }

    if(check=true){
        System.out.println("Found Result: "+sname);
    }
    else if (check=false){
        System.out.println("Not Found.");
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison. (1) Don't use `== true` with booleans, just use `if(check)`, (2) don't bother checking the inverse, just use `else`.

Comment: @chrylis It works!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

a. You need to break of for loop once you see that you have the name being equals:

```
boolean check = false;
for(i = 0; i < namearray.length; i++){
      if(namearray[i].equals(sname)) {
         check=true;
         break;
      }
}//assuming you are doing it for study purpose or i would use name.contains(sname); rather than for loop.
```

b. You dont check for conditions using "=" (in your case it means two things you first assign value and then your if always evaluates to true), instead if would do it like:

```
if(check){
    System.out.println("Found Result: "+sname);
} else{
    System.out.println("Not Found.");
}
```

Comment: thanks! its worked now!

Answer (score 0):

Replace check=true and check=false by check==true check == false.

Comment: it gives me invalid assignment operator errors...